# Is this proof / assumption correct? Obtaining T from Q v R -> S, S -> T

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, solution-verification

I am new to propositional logic / deductive proofs,
I have the following:

- Q v R => S
- S => T

---

Therefore T

I have tried to use the fact that there is a hypothetical syllogism to obtain
Q v R => T

(this is the part where i'm unsure)

Can i assume, Q v R, then assume S, and use the result to apply Modus Ponens to the 2nd premise to obtain T?

1. Q v R => S
2. S => T
3. Q v R   (assumption) start of sub proof
4. S       (from 1 & 3) modus ponens
5. T       (From 2 & 4) modus ponens

Comment: No, it's not possible to prove $T$ from those two premises. The proof you gave proves $(Q\lor R)\implies T$, not $T$, because of the undischarged assumption in step 3.

Comment: Ahh, thankyou for your quick response, i've probably done something wrong earlier on ( i had another premise above these 2)